# How to change content of a certain column on a table?

Tags: javascript

I want to change the innerText of "Start date" column on this table.

**Here's the code :**

```
<tr id="currentRow">
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Position</th>
  <th>Office</th>
  <th>Age</th>
  <th>Start date</th>
  <th>Salary</th>           
</tr>
```

I tried this code below but it didn't work.

```
document.getElementById("currentRow").td[4] = "this is a text";
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `.innerHTML` if you want to change the content of the selected element using `querySelectorAll`, like :

```
document.querySelectorAll('#currentRow th')[4].innerHTML = "this is a text";
```

**NOTE :** Make sure that your table contain at least one`td`.

Hope this helps.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#currentRow th')[4].innerHTML = "this is a text";
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="currentRow">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Office</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Start date</th>
    <th>Salary</th>

  </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: But getElementById not working for me , querySelectorAll is working.

Comment: probably cause theres no .td property? :/

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table>
<tr id="currentRow">
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Position</th>
  <th>Office</th>
  <th>Age</th>
  <th>Start date</th>
  <th>Salary</th>           
</tr>
</table>
<script>
document.getElementById("currentRow").children[4].innerHTML = "this is a text";
</script>
```

Theres no *td* in an element but rather a *children* array.

Comment: @user3080440 glad to help ;) as this question is answered, it would be your job now to hit the green checkmark on one of these two answers ( zakaria was first, just sayin ;))